# What is the title: aliens visit dead earth, revive the dead

Tags: story-identification

A story where aliens visit a dead earth, and revive the dead. They visit a museum and begin by reviving a dead Egyptian, then a 1930s boozer. They hit a snag when they revive a recently deceased. He displays powers. They drop bombs but none explode. The aliens are tricked into plunging into the sun by the revived human

Comment: "The Monster" a.k.a. "Resurrection" by A. E. van Vogt. A very popular story, identified many times on this site.

Comment: Yes. "The Monster" is the title. I have it in Transfinite. Thank you muchly